# Is it possible to detect stage failure in runing Jenkins pipeline using GraphListener?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Im having troubles detecting when a stage has finished with failures using `GraphListener.Synchronous` . So far I've tried:

- Detect `FlowNodes` with `ErrorAction`, none appeared
- Detect `AtomNodes` (the ones with "skipped due to previuous failure(s)"), but couldn't.
- Access to `rawBuild.result`, which is null before the build finishes.
- Basically checking any public method or field involving `currentBuild`, `currentBuild.rawBuild`, `Executor`, `WorkUnit`,... But I haven't found anything so far.

Is there any way to detect failures on stages using a listener on the execution for declarative pipelines? Where `CpsScript` or `CpsFlowExecution` stores which stage failed so I can access that field too? Does a plugin need to be developed for this kind of tasks?

Comment: You can query Jenkins API, e.g. `https://your-jenkins/job/your-job/1/api/json`. We use that extensively.

Comment: @MaratC, is the information of the build available *during* the build? Specifically if I query this API during a listener `onNewHead` event will it contain the info about the stage falied even though the pipeline didnt finished?

Comment: I've tried reading `currentBuild.rawBuild.getApi().bean.result` but its null until the job reaches the *Declarative: Post Actions* stage

Comment: I can confirm that _some info_ returns from that url (with `curl`) while the build is run, regarding the listeners I have absolutely no idea as I have never used them. You are welcome to try.

Comment: Thinking about it, we got there by analyzing BlueOcean requests, this API is what BlueOcean uses.

Comment: are you implementing your own implementation of GraphListener.Synchronous? Because by default it does notification in batches. Also, are your stages using throws or how are errors being set? The other problem, not every tool in jenkins throws errors in the same way. So need a bit more information.

Comment: We use logging, as a way to detect errors, but we still have to go into the console and look, the actual fail notification just says it failed, not so much why.

Comment: @Caperneoignis, yes I am giving my own implementation of GraphListener.Synchronous,  errors are thrown by compilation failures sometimes, other times set by sonar plugin methods like `waitForQualityGate`

Comment: I'm not really interested on the failure message, for me this should be just a way to detect which stage failed, create a notification inside the GraphListener and send it. The notification will have the stage name so based on that name you know what happened and if you need more info you can always go check inside the log of the job run.